# An empty matplotlib figure without an axes is not getting displayed in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using macOS version 11.4 on MacBook Pro with M1 chip with below versions of the software:

- Python 3.8.8
- matplotlib 3.3.4
- Jupyter notebook 6.3.0
- jupyter core     : 4.7.1
- ipython 7.22.0

A blank figure does not render in the notebook however a figure with at least 1 subplot or axes does show up in the notebook. Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? I had previously tried the same thing in windows laptop and even the blank figure would show up. Below is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the below line does not show any image
fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1,0,0,0.1), figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
plt.show();
# the output is - "<Figure size 576x288 with 0 Axes>"

#whereas, if I add a subplot to the figure, it renders a figure inline in the notebook
fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1,0,0,0.1), figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.show();
```

[A subplot within the figure is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBnhu.png)

Comment: You can try using a different backend. Eg. `%matplotlib tk` ahead of your other magics and importing matplotlib. See the output of `matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk` for other interactive backends (some may not be available on your system).

Comment: In-line backend uses bbox_inches tight to shrink the figure to only include artists in the figure.  You have no artists so your figure shrinks to nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, Yes changing the backend to tk does render an empty figure.